# Web standard: markup for navigating next/previous page and browsers support

Tags: navigation, cross-browser, web-standards, browser-support

A lot of web-pages structured by pagination or have natural meaning for Next/Previous page (forums/blogs/news).

Are there web standard that allow marking such links?

What browsers have support for key binding to follow next/previous page (to avoid searching for next link, which have different styling and positioning in different sites)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML5 defines the [sequential link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#sequential-link-types) [`next`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-next) and [`prev`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/links.html#link-type-prev).

User agents could pick this up and do something with it (like offering a key binding, showing a button, etc.).

Comment: There are also `index` and `up` link types! Thanks for answer. Another source of docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types

Answer (score 0):

Even there is accepted answer I must add some notes.

I discovered that most forum/blog engine as well as Google/Yahoo/etc services uses `next`/`prev`/`canonical` `rel`.

Opera browser uses `rel="next"` to load next page when you at the and of page and type `SPACE`. So do Firefox with https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/space-next/ add-on. Or more powerful navigation with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-Us/firefox/addon/link-widgets/ add-on.